# How to Import Programatically a file or an XML string in Acumatica that supports import XML

Tags: acumatica

I just wanted to know if this is possible via code, I  think of as a post-installation of my customization which needs some imported XML that cannot be included in the Customization Project objects. I looked up on Customization Code Plug-in, this is the solution but I do not know where to start to manipulate the File Upload or Import an XML then I pass a string variable to make it readable for the screen to accept the Import XML and just save the data.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I would consider just including in customization necessary xml staff, as file. Then in Customization plugin just read from that xml, and persist it wherever needed in db.